# cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string> C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary, return

I'm trying to add a new List for each loop in the code below to a dictionary, but I'm currently struggling with the following error:

> cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

```
public class WeaponGen{
Dictionary<string, List<string>> weapons = new Dictionary <string, List<string>>(); 

public void WeaponGeneration(int GenerationCount)
{
    Weapon weapon = new Weapon(); //this class contains basic calculation methods
    weapons.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < GenerationCount; i++)
    {
        string listname = "weapon" + i;
        string id = Random.Range(1, 41).ToString();

        List<string>[] _lists = new List<string>[GenerationCount];
        _lists[i] = new List<string>();

        weapons.Add(listname, _lists[i].Add(id)); //this line throws an error
        weapons.Add(listname, _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetName(id))); //this line throws an error
        weapons.Add(listname, _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetRarity(id))); //this line throws an error
        weapons.Add(listname, _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetType(id))); //this line throws an error
        weapons.Add(listname, _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetDmg(id).ToString())); //this line throws an error
        weapons.Add(listname, _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetSpeed(id).ToString())); //this line throws an error
        weapons.Add(listname, _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetCost(id).ToString())); //this line throws an error
    }
}}
```

Since my coding skills are definitly lacking in some aspects, I figured someone with a better grasp on the language could help me out. Every help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

List `add` method does not return any value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2.

So, if I understood your idea correctly, you need to fill the list with needed values and add it itself to the dictionary, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GenerationCount; i++)
{
    string listname = "weapon" + i;
    string id = Random.Range(1, 41).ToString();

    List<string>[] _lists = new List<string>[GenerationCount];
    _lists[i] = new List<string>();

    _lists[i].Add(id); 
    _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetName(id)); 
    _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetRarity(id)); 
    _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetType(id)); 
    _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetDmg(id).ToString());
    _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetSpeed(id).ToString()); 
    _lists[i].Add(weapon.GetCost(id).ToString());
    weapons.Add(listname, _lists[i]);
}
```

P.S. What is it `Random.Range`? Is it some extention method? In any case, it seems to be dangerous to generate id's based on random value in such small interval. Why not simple use `i.ToString()`?

Comment: Thank you, this is a very quick and easy solution to my problem :) I'd upvote your answer if I could!

Comment: This code is for a game I'm working on and Random.Range is inherited from the UnityEngine namespace. I'm getting my values from a .csv file which has a row for id's. I use this method to randomly pick an ID from that list (the interval is basically the upper and lower bound of that .csv) and generate the relevant weapon data for that ID. So these id's are actually like keys for me :D

Comment: Ok, this is the nice explanation)